# How to filter on Access Report subtotal

Tags: ms-access, filter, ms-access-2013, subtotal

Have an access report that shows training programs, and which employees should be but are not trained on that program.  This query is fine.  Problem is that we want to only display on the report training programs which have more than 10 employees untrained.  So we have the total of untrained for each program in a subtotal, but we want to filter on that value.

How can this be done?

EDIT:

Here is pass-through query to SQL Server

```
SELECT T.ProgramTitle
       ,T.ProgramCode
       ,AE.Code AS 'AvantiCode'
       ,AE.FullName
       ,AE.FirstName
       ,AE.LastName
       ,AE.Department
       ,C.Position
       ,AE.Shift
FROM HR_Curriculum C
INNER JOIN HR_Trainings T ON C.TrainingID = T.TrainingID
INNER JOIN HR_EmployeeDetails ED ON C.Position = ED.Postion
INNER JOIN Avanti_Employees AE ON ED.AvantiRecID = AE.RecID
LEFT JOIN HR_Employeetrainings ET ON C.TrainingID = ET.TrainingID
                                 AND ED.AvantiRecID = ET.AvantiRecID
LEFT JOIN HR_TrainingVersion V ON V.VersionID = ET.VersionID
WHERE terminated = 0
       AND T.Active = - 1
       AND CompletedDate IS NULL

GROUP BY T.ProgramTitle
       ,T.ProgramCode
       ,AE.Code
       ,AE.FullName
       ,AE.FirstName
       ,AE.LastName
       ,AE.Department
       ,C.Position
       ,AE.Shift
Order by programtitle
```

Comment: Show us your query and if you can a screen shot of the report. I think your question doesn't quite fill in all the holes we need to adequately answer your question. And you say the query is fine, but I would think this would be done in the query and the report would be used to arrange/group as you seem necessary.

Comment: I see it's a pass-through query to SQL Server..I think you can use this query as a subquery and use `Count()` to identify which programs have >10 employees untrained, or you can use a Common Table Expression to Return the results from your query, and then only Select records from there `HAVING SomeCount > 10`

Comment: It's bad practice to filter records at the report level. You want to be returning *exactly* what you expect to see in your report, that way if something goes wrong or you need to fix something, you're working with a recordset instead of playing with the reporting functionality (*which can get tricky*)

Comment: So rework the query to filter there?

Comment: I would. I would see it as you having two options. Keep your report and query, and create another report with this desired functionality and your new query filtering by Counts of Untrained Employees by Programs in case you ever need your original report/query.. Or just make the changes to this query

Answer (score 1):

Consider an [inline view](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php), using a grouped by table alias with `HAVING` clause.

Try adding one more inner join:

```
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TrainingID, ProgramTitle, ProgramCode
FROM HR_Trainings
GROUP BY TrainingID, ProgramTitle, ProgramCode
HAVING Count(TrainingID) > 10) AS Trainings10More
ON Trainings10More.TrainingID = T.TrainingID
```

Comment: While I'm sure this would work, I find using a CTE (or a derived query) to be a much more readable approach.